# Are copper pours hidden by default in EAGLE?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, pcb-layers, ground-plane, copper-pour

I'm looking at the EAGLE board file from the [Arduino wiki page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/pmwiki.php?n=Main/ArduinoBoardProMini), and I feel like I must be missing something - none of the ground pins of U1 appear to be connected to anything:

[image: Arduino Pro Mini]

As you can see, the GND pin on the bottom right is unconnected, as is the GND at pin 5. The GND at pin 3 is connected to a via which goes... nowhere?

Here's the board file with just the top layer showing, for further clarity:

[image: Arduino Pro Mini - Top Layer]

For more weirdness, you can see here that there's a weird trace going off to nowhere from the ground side of the upper decoupling cap.

Admittedly I'm not used to using EAGLE, so I tried the brute-force approach of enabling every single layer in case I was missing an obscurely named inner layer or ground pour, but as far as I can tell there's no connection at all.

What am I missing? Is the board file missing stuff, or have I got something hidden?

Comment: I changed the question/title to reflect a failure of Eagle to tell that you needed to run a command instead of a failure on the design (a lack of ground connections). If you disagree with the change please revert it.

Comment: @WesleyLee Edited slightly to be a bit more generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a "[Ratsnest](http://web.mit.edu/xavid/arch/i386_rhel4/help/75.htm)" command for Eagle to render the planes/polygons.

Unrendered on the left, rendered on the right. Ground highlighted.

I'm only showing layers 1, vias and pads here.

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Knew there was something weird going on; didn't realise a lot of the functionality in EAGLE is hidden behind commands like that. Good to know.

Comment: @Polynomial - glad to be of help. I generally don't like Eagle very much but I can't get away from it because of typing the commands. After you get used to it it is quite faster than clicking buttons on the UI.

Comment: My usual is Multisim/Ultiboard, so I'm a bit spoiled.